# How do you maintain data retain and update between the UAT and Production Environments?

Tags: sql-server, production-environment, test-environments

I'm trying to get a solution for our UAT and Production Environment databases. The idea is that from time to time we will need to update the UAT environment with live data, but also to be able to retain the data used for testing purposes.

Do you have the same issue? How to you maintain the data in this scenario? Are there any products on the market to help retaining and moving the data across from Production to UAT/DEV? 
P.S.I'm not worried about data obfuscation for now, but only moving data across - the schema will match within all the environments.

Thank you

Comment: testers will need to have seperate environment in your case

Comment: Thank you... I was hoping that won't be the case :)